# python not reading in a web page

Tags: python, html, css

I run the python (server?) in the background that creates the pages etc.

I then have my usual `index.html` file and the header and nav bar are in a /shared folder.

On my `index.html` page, I have the following code :-

```
 <html> 
    %include('shared/html-head.html') 
    %include('shared/html-nav.html')
```

for some reason, this is not loading the files. They are there and correctly named and are `.html` files.

The page in Chrome displays the following at the top of the page:-           `%include('shared/html-head.html') %include('shared/html-nav.html')`

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why? Because your web server served it `index.html` literally. Why your server served the files literally instead of running them through the template engine would be a great question... if we had any idea what your web server looked like. You only mention you are using bottle; [tag:bottle] tag would have been useful (OTOH, this has nothing to do with [tag:jquery], [tag:javascript], [tag:css]); and we can't tell you anything without you posting your server code.

Comment: https://github.com/Welsh-Ddraig/cs4hs

These are my files and layout. the shared folder holds common parts of the web pages, so I only have to change the page once.

Comment: Works for me (using `python2 webpage.py`). Can you check that you are using the latest `bottle`? (`pip2 install --upgrade bottle`). I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: THANKS. PEBKAC error. I was just clicking on the index.html file once I was running the .py file. Not going through localhost:8080. I knew it would be a noob problem, something I was doing wrong. Many thanks